# How do I get the Average Method to give correct output in Java

Tags: java

I am expecting 3.5 as result from average method, but I get 3.0. No idea why. I expected Double to give me the result, but no.
java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class Hangman {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    intList.add(3);
    intList.add(2);
    intList.add(7);
    intList.add(2);

    System.out.println("The variance number is : ");
    System.out.println(sum(intList));
    System.out.println(intList.size());
    System.out.println(average(intList));
  }

  public static int sum(ArrayList<Integer> intList) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < intList.size(); counter++) {
        sum = sum + intList.get(counter);
    }
    return sum;
  }

  public static double average(ArrayList<Integer> intList) {
    double avg = sum(intList) / (intList.size());

    return avg;
  }

  public static ArrayList<Double> subtract(ArrayList<Integer> intList) {
    ArrayList<Double> subtracted = new ArrayList<Double>();
    for (double subtract : intList) {
        subtracted.add((double) (subtract - average(intList)));
    }
    return subtracted;
  }

  public static double variance(ArrayList<Integer> intList) {
    double sumDiffsSquared = 0.0;
    double avg = average(intList);
    for (int value : intList) {
        double diff = value - avg;
        diff *= diff;
        sumDiffsSquared += diff;
    }
    return (sumDiffsSquared / (intList.size() - 1));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum` needs to return a double, otherwise when you do a

```
sum(intList) / (intList.size());
```

in your `average` method, it truncates the value calculated down to an integer, and then puts that value in double form.

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs to return a double value.

Change your method to

```
public static double sum(ArrayList<Integer> intList) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < intList.size(); counter++) {
        sum = sum + intList.get(counter);
    }
    return sum;
  }
```

and you should be doing fine.

Answer (score 0):

Though the type of `avg` is double , `sum()` method is returning a Integer value. So you have return a double from `sum()` method

Answer (score 0):

double avg = (double)sum(intList) / (intList.size());